# Why was "A Hard Day's Night" filmed in black and white?

Tags: production, a-hard-days-night

The 1964 film [*A Hard Day's Night*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Hard_Day%27s_Night_(film)) was filmed in black and white at a time where films in color were being received more favorably, especially by younger audiences.  Since this film stars all four original Beatle members and it was a musical comedy, I assume that it was marketed for a younger audience.

**Is there a reason why filmmakers chose to film this movie in black and white instead of color?**

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4158/49).

Answer (score 6):

There are two disputed theories on why B&W for this film

**Stylistic**
The movie was supposed to be modeled after documentaries or news coverage of the day which were often in black and white typically.  The artistic vision was to create a mockumentary of a day in the life of the band.  While the film itself was fantastical and funny, they wanted to film it in a style that was more cinema verite.
[source](http://legendsrevealed.com/entertainment/2013/07/15/was-a-hard-days-night-filmed-in-black-and-white-to-save-money/)

**Budget**
The film was said to be greenlit to get the rights to the soundtrack itself with the film thought of as an afterthought.  As such, the budget of roughly $500,000 USD (considered low budget even in 1964) was a welcome price to pay to secure rights to the soundtrack.  Film historian, Stephen Glynn said the movie was "a low-budget exploitation movie to milk the latest brief musical craze for all it was worth."

sources [1](http://flavorwire.com/465788/25-things-you-didnt-know-about-a-hard-days-night/view-all) [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Hard_Day%27s_Night_(film)#Production)

Either way, the black and white gives it a timeless quality and likely also saved United Artists lots of money resulting in a classic movie.